# ¿Cómo evitar que se añadan productos al carro al refrescar página en Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy trabajando en una tienda web con Wordpress y Woocommerce. A la hora de mandar los productos al carro, tengo varias funciones tanto por el front como por el back que evitan que se sobrepase una cantidad determinada de cada producto. Todo funciona bien.
El único problema que no consigo resolver, es que si yo añado un producto (momento en el que sale un mensaje de confirmación que dice que el producto se ha metido en el carro correctamente) y seguidamente recargo el navegador, me vuelve a añadir tanto productos como haya añadido en la última iteración. Por ejemplo:
Vendo tartas y en cada pedido solo se pueden pedir 5 unidades. En el input de la cantidad meto 2 unidades y las añado al carro, seguidamente refresco el navegador y entonces me añade otras 2 unidades y si vuelvo a refrescar me añadirá otras 2, de manera que en el último paso de la compra me dirá que quiero comprar 6 unidades.
Al final no será posible y solo dejará comprar 5 por las validaciones que he comentado anteriormente, por lo que no va a causar grandes problemas para mí. Pero creo que sí será algo incómodo y feo para el usuario.
¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Has intentado hacer algo en código?

Comment: Hola. Todo el código que tengo consiste en dos funciones realizadas en el archivo functions.php y validaciones a nivel de front en mi archivo js. Una de las funciones se encarga de evitar que el usuario pueda seleccionar más unidades de las establecidas en la página del producto y la otra de que no pueda finalizar la compra en la página del carrito. Podría haberlas puesto aquí pero creo que no aportarían nada a la pregunta inicial...

Answer (score 0):

Sabes si al agregar se genera un query, tipo ?add-to-cart=ID o parecido, si es así puedes probar agregando esto en tu archivo functions.php

```
add_action('add_to_cart_redirect', 'resolve_dupes_add_to_cart_redirect');

function resolve_dupes_add_to_cart_redirect($url = false) {
     if(!empty($url)) { return $url; }
     return get_bloginfo('wpurl').add_query_arg(array(), remove_query_arg('add-to-cart'));
}
```

Esto agregara una redirección después de agregar el producto evitando que se vuelva a agregar el producto

Fuentes:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46882463/wordpress-woocommerce-product-is-being-added-to-cart-on-page-refresh

Comment: Sabes si al agregar se genera un query, tipo ?add-to-cart=ID o parecido, si es así puedes probar agregando esto en tu archivo functions.php